# Manipulação do JSON com Asp.net Web API

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

Olá, estou montando uma aplicação educacional onde eu tenho um calendário de cursos. Neste projeto estou utilizando um calendário jquery, e este utiliza um json para montagem das datas que possui evento agendado.

O pluggin ([w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/](http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/)) utiliza o seguinte json para montar os eventos no calendário:

```
"2014-12-22": { "url" : "link curso" },
"2014-12-26": { "url" : "url do curso"},
"2015-01-12": { "url" : "link deste curso"}
```

Utilizando a minha aplicação web api, consegui gerar o seguinte json

```
{
    "data": "29-12-2014",
    "url": "gestao-agropecuaria"
},
{
    "data": "26-12-2014",
    "url": "producao-animal"
},
{
    "data": "06-01-2015",
    "url": "teste"
}
```

Abaixo o método actionResult e o método onde é criada a query mysql para consulta no banco de dados

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var events = new Admin.AppClass.Agenda();
    return Ok(events.ListarDatasCalendario());
}



public DataTable ListarDatasCalendario()
{
            Mysql mysql = new Mysql();

            try
            {

                return mysql.ExecutarComando(@" SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.data, '%d-%m-%Y') as data, 
                                                               c.nome as url 
                                                          FROM agenda a, cursos c
                                                         WHERE a.curso = c.id
                                                         ORDER BY data DESC");

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
}
```

Alguém pode me auxiliar de como eu consigo configurar meu json de maneira aceitável para funcionar no pluggin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou demonstrar como retornar uma lista com o json esperado, tente converter o seu `DataTable` pra preencher esse dicionário:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> ListarDatasCalendario()
{
    var lista = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    lista.Add("2014-01-01", new { url = "url 1" });
    lista.Add("2014-01-02", new { url = "url 2" });
    lista.Add("2014-01-03", new { url = "url 3" });

    return lista;
}
```

Comment: Valeu @iuristona, obrigado cara, deu tudo certo. Abraços